# Kendo Datetimepicker Renders Different Once Published

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue where my kendo datetimerpicker is rendering differently between when I run on my local machine and when the webpage has been published

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
            animation: {
                close: {
                    effects: "faceOut zoom:out",
                    duration: 300
                },
                open: {
                    effects: "faceIn zoom:in",
                    duration: 300
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Highwatermark, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Highwatermark, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "datetimepicker" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Highwatermark, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Running on local machine:
[image: Running on local machine]

Published:
[image: Published]

It still works if I click where the calendar and clock should be but I'm not sure why the images aren't showing up.

I'm also not sure why the datetimepicker is stretching so far over in both cases.

Comment: I bet you did not deploy all of your resource file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `form-control` CSS class is related to the expanding:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap#use-form-control-bootstrap-css-class

You can restore the standard DateTimePicker width of `15em` with a custom CSS rule:

```
.k-datetimepicker.form-control {
    width: 15em;
}
```

If you need only some DateTimePickers to maintain their default width, apply another custom CSS class in `htmlAttributes` in addition to `form-control` and use it in the CSS selector:

```
.k-datetimepicker.form-control.my-no-expand {
    width: 15em;
}
```

Assuming that the main theme images (**sprite.png** and **sprite_2x.png**) do exist on the production server, then the problem with the missing icons can be caused by the CSS bundling configuration:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/fundamentals#css-bundling

Comment: The custom CSS rule worked, and it turns out I had the theme image folders in the within the project folder but not actually added to the project so they weren't being published to the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Check your kendo CSS files. Sometimes the relative addresses need modification to apply corrently. It is common issue. For example in css file you have something like:

```
background-image:url('Bootstrap/sprite.png')
```

which should change to

```
background-image:url('2015.3.930/Bootstrap/sprite.png')
```